# New MySQL user while loop questions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to use this for a project at work, and am running into some trouble.  I have a large database (58mil rows) that I have figured out how to query down to what I want and then write this row in to a separate table.  Here is my code so far:

```
insert into emissionfactors(pollutantID,fuelTypeID,sourceTypeID,emissionFactor)
select pollutantID,fuelTypeID,sourceTypeID,avg(ratePerDistance) as emissionFactor
from onroad_run_1.rateperdistance 
    where pollutantID=45
    and fuelTypeID=2
    and sourceTypeID=32;
```

I have about 60 different pollutant ID's, and currently I am manually changing the pollutantID number on line 5 and executing the script to write the row into my 'emissionfactors' table.  Each run takes 45 seconds and I have several other fuel types and source types to do so this could take like 8 hours of clicking every 45 seconds. I have some training in matlab and thought I could put a while loop around the above code, create an index, and have it loop through from 1 to 184 on the pollutant IDs but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here are my goals:
- loop the pollutantID from 1 to 184.
-- not all integers are in this range, so need it to simply add one to the index and check to see if that number is found in the pollutantID column if the index is not found.
-- if the index number is found in the pollutant ID column, execute my above code to write the data into my other table

Comment: You have tagged this both as mysql and oracle.  Are you in fact using both types?

Comment: I assume you are not using Oracle because your title says MySQL and the code you posted isn't valid in Oracle.  It shouldn't be valid in any database but MySQL is, err, "helpful".  You have an aggregate function `avg` along with some non-aggregated columns but you're not doing a `group by`.  The database should require a `group by` in that case.  Include a `group by` and then the `between` syntax in the answer works.

Comment: @JustinCave you are correct about the Oracle tag, I am working in MySQL.  Sorry again, new user here, just doing my best to get this done easily.  Thanks for the help, let me try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a while loop, all you need is to change your where clause to use a BETWEEN clause and also tell it what you want to base the average on by adding a GROUP BY clause

```
insert into emissionfactors(pollutantID,fuelTypeID,sourceTypeID,emissionFactor)
select pollutantID,fuelTypeID,sourceTypeID,avg(ratePerDistance) as emissionFactor
from onroad_run_1.rateperdistance 
    where pollutantID BETWEEN 1 AND 184
    and fuelTypeID=2
    and sourceTypeID=32
GROUP BY pollutantID , fuelTypeID, sourceTypeID;
```

If in fact you want the entire range of the pollutantID, fuelTypeID and  sourceTypeID that exists you can just remove the where clause altogether.

```
insert into emissionfactors(pollutantID,fuelTypeID,sourceTypeID,emissionFactor)
select pollutantID,fuelTypeID,sourceTypeID,avg(ratePerDistance) as emissionFactor
from onroad_run_1.rateperdistance 
GROUP BY pollutantID , fuelTypeID, sourceTypeID;
```

You also don't need to check if the row exists before executing the query, as if it doesn't exist and returns no rows it just won't insert any.

As to the speed issue, you will need to look at adding some table indexes to your table to improve performance.  In this case an index that has pollutantID, fuelTypeID and sourceTypeID would speed things up greatly.

My advice, ask for help at work.  It is better to admit early that you do not know how to do something and get proper help, as you also mention that you have different fuel types that you want, but the details of that are missing from your question.

Comment: I did a test run `between 1 and 6`, which includes numbers that have no corresponding pollutant ID (1,2,3,4) and two numbers that have unique pollutant ID's (5,6).  The output just returned 1 row with the `emissionfactor` as a sum of the two individual emission factors from pollutants 5 and 6 instead of two unique rows with their own emission factor for the different pollutants.  Any other suggestions? Edit: I would ask for help at work but we're an environmental consulting firm & nobody besides me has previous coding experience haha I've had to learn MySQL from the ground up for this project!

Comment: Ah, that is because you have put an avg(ratePerDistance) in your select statement. What do you want the average based on?

Comment: so for each vehicleID and fuelTypeID there are 60 some pollutantID's that my program has output.  Each of these pollutantID's has 300-400 different `ratePerDistance` values.  I need the average of these values that correspond to that vehicleID, fuelTypeId, and pollutantID.  I hope that makes sense, please let me know if you need further explaination

Comment: @Dijkgraff, wow, THANK YOU for the help.  I am glad I got there almost by myself, but I would not have been able to do this so easily without you. THANK YOU AGAIN!!